# Add product and category association in Volusion through Volusion API

Tags: php, xml, api, volusion

I am trying to add products to the Volusion store using the XML API.  I have found the following page which outlines how to associate products with categories and I am finding that it is confusing me.

On this page it states that only two columns are required a ProductID and a CategoryID.

http://support.volusion.com/article/product-management-categories-products-link-developer

However I have found that when I try to export my Products table they do not have an ID column.  The unique constraint on that table is based on the ProductCode column.

With that said I did an export of the Categories_Products_Link table and it gave me 3 columns.  ID, CategoryID and Auto_Maintenance_Column.

As you can see this does not even line-up with the page that states ProductId is a column.

So I have to ask is the column name ID or ProductID?  Also when I did the export I noticed numerical id's in the ID column and NOT ProductCodes so i would wonder what data I should send through as the ProductID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign products to categories using the API with XML data you will have to send a POST request to the API using the following format.

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>
    <xmldata>
    <Categories_Products_Link>
        <CategoryID>108</CategoryID>
        <ProductID>37606</ProductID>
    </Categories_Products_Link>
</xmldata>
```

See this for more info...

https://support.volusion.com/article/product-management-categories-products-link-developer

You would use your API URL with credentials and remember to use the correct import mode. I used Insert-Update shown below but your should use whatever is appropriate for your needs.

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=name@website.com &EncryptedPassword=AA3312590F0B4577E9C660436C7A5244649352B277A557FC87990E6C0CF3789A&Import=Insert-Update
```

See this for more info...

http://support.volusion.com/article/api-integration-introduction-developer

The ProductID is not the product code and not the ID column in the Categories Products Link export. To get each product's ProductID you could run and SQL query like so.

```
SELECT Products_Joined.ProductCode, Products_Joined.ProductID FROM Products_Joined WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY Products_Joined.ProductCode
```

Don't forget to send the headers with the POST request

```
"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
"Content-Action", "Volusion_API"
```

Comment: Thanks yea I had finally figured out that the ProductID is required and that is not the ProductCode, even though if you use the ProductCode you will  get a success message and an entry in the Categories_Products_Link table.  I was making the switch from CSV generation to the API and csv you only used ProductCodes.  Thanks for this assistance and explanation.

Comment: Can you explain the query?? what it meant by " WITH (NOLOCK)". When i run this query and getting this error. 

False Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. 1

Can you tell me.